# disable background when popup opens

Tags: jquery, blur

I am trying to disable the background after a popup is triggered in the window. The following code I am using on a div to display a form to enter information in to be passed to a db.

The html:

```
<div id="add_project">
    <a href="#" title="Close">
        <div class="close">
            <p class="x">x</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <h3>Add Project</h3>
    <form method="post">
        <table width="300" align="center">
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr style="border: none">
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="project name" placeholder="Enter Project Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr style="border: none">
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="project description" placeholder="Project Description" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr style="border: none">
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="button" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border: none">
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jQuery to hide and show the div:

```
$("#add_project").hide();
$("#addProject").click(function () {
    $("#add_project").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".close").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ ...

Comment: Here is a jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/arUgAnur/1

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/a-quick-javascript-lightbox/ might help you

Answer (score 1):

There is always more than one way to do things.  I would set the div you intend to pop-up as a dialogue and simply open it when needed.  That will automatically overlay the rest of the page and prevent user entry.  Here's and example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divDialog").dialog(
            {
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 700,
                buttons: { Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
            }

        );
    });
</script>

<div id="divDialog" title="Data Modification">
  //elements to enter or modify data
</div>
```

and then on the click process:

```
$('#divDialog').dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q392B/61/)

if it is working fine then You need to change JQuery as like below..

**Your HTML**

```
<div class="close" style="background-color:yellow"><a href="#" title="Close">
    <div ><p class="x">x</p></div></a></div>
 <div id="add_project" style="background-color:green" >      
<h3>Add Project</h3>


        <table width="300" align="center">

        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>

        <tr style="border: none">

        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="project name" placeholder="Enter Project Name" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr style="border: none">
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="project description" placeholder="Project Description" /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr></tr>

        <tr style="border: none">

        <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Save" /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="border: none">

        <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Cancel" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

**JQuery code...**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").fadeOut(500);
        $("#add_project").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).fadeOut(1000);
            $(".close").fadeIn(500);

        });

    $(".close").click(function() {
            $('#add_project').show();
            $('#add_project').fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).fadeOut(500);

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#add_project").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $('#background_element').css({"backgroundImage":"none"});
    //Or
    $('#background_element').hide();
});
```

To show it again after popup closes.

```
$("#add_project").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $('#background_element').css({"backgroundImage":"yourbackgroundimage.gif"});
    //Or
    $('#background_element').show();
});
```